# would it possible to do this in one mysql query only

Tags: mysql

Could this be done with one query?

table day:

```
dID
enable
holiday
fewMore
```

table segment:

```
d_ID //foregn key to day->dID
startTime
endTime
fewMore
```

query:

```
SELECT dID, enabled,holiday,  
       TIME_TO_SEC(dHaurs) as wsTimeHHmm,
       DATE_FORMAT(dDate, '%d') as dateForComparing,
       DATE_FORMAT(start, '%H:%i') as startTime,
       DATE_FORMAT(end, '%H:%i') as endTime 
FROM day d                                  
LEFT JOIN segment ws 
ON ws.d_ID = d.dID
WHERE dDate BETWEEN '" . $startDate . "' AND  '" . $endDate . "'                                
ORDER by dateForComparing
```

result I am getting:

```
dID:10, start time:08:00, end time:09:00, holiday:0, enabled:1
dID:10, start time:09:00, end time:10:00, holiday:0, enabled:1
dID:11, start time:08:00, end time:10:00, holiday:1, enabled:1
```

but I would like to group all segments with same d_ID.

```
dID:10, array((start time:08:00, end time:09:00),(start time:09:00, end time:10:00)), holiday:0, enabled:1
```

I tried with `GROUP_CONCAT(wsID,start, end)` ... `GROUP BY dID` but I am not sure is that right way and also I am not able to use function `DATE_FORMAT(start, '%H:%i') as startTime`

could this be done with mysql only?

UPDATE:
right now, I am creating array from result:

```
  $returnData  [] =array(array(dID =>"dID",
                         endTime => $end_time,
                         startTime=> $start_time,...
                               ),
                        array( enabled=> $enabled,
                                holiday =>$holiday
                               )
                         );
echo json_encode($returnData);
```

Comment: Why you want to get data in this way? How you will use that data?

Comment: as ajax response, to update page (jquery)

Comment: Do you want to get strings like this `dID:10, array((start time:08:00, end time:09:00),(start time:09:00, end time:10:00)), holiday:0, enabled:1` for each `dID`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, pleas don't get me wrong, right now I have solution, I just asked if is it possible to do the same only in mysql query.. as with `$.each` I am looping for holiday and enabled more then once, unnecessary

Comment: i am not expert of php and mysql, but i think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return arrays in MySQL, but you could manipulate the output like this:

```
dID:10, start time:08:00, end time:10:00, holiday:0, enabled:1
```

Comment: I need them separately `8-9, 9-10`

Comment: oh I just saw something: Try again with the "GROUP BY" and "GROUP_CONCAT(start, end)"

Comment: `SELECT dID, enabled,holiday,  
       TIME_TO_SEC(dHaurs) as wsTimeHHmm,
       DATE_FORMAT(dDate, '%d') as dateForComparing,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(start, '%H:%i'),
       DATE_FORMAT(end, '%H:%i')) as time 
FROM day d                                  
LEFT JOIN segment ws 
ON ws.d_ID = d.dID
WHERE dDate BETWEEN '" . $startDate . "' AND  '" . $endDate . "'                                
ORDER by dateForComparing HROUP BY dID`

Comment: I tried that as well, first day, but `date_format` function wan't work within `group_concat` :( thank you for you effort :)

Comment: You can try to put them in another Select clause. Although i doubt that the performance would be great.